# Выдает ошибку "Cannot find module "create-react-class" react.js

Tags: reactjs

Не знаю в чем дело и почему консоль ругается. Вот код:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Timer extends React.Component{
 getInitialState: function(){
  return{
   seconds: 0
  };
},
  componentDidMount: function(){
   this.timer = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
  },

  tick: function(){
   this.setState({seconds: this.state.seconds + 1});
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function(){
   clearInterval(this.timer);
  },

  render: function(){
   return(
    <h5>Прошло: {this.state.seconds}</h5>
   )
  }
}
export default Timer
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Объясните что не так? В чем причина ошибки?

Answer (score 0):

В новых версиях createReactClass - deprecated

класс можно сделать так

```
class Timer extends React.Component{
....
}

export default Timer;
```

или использовать полифил:

```
npm install create-react-class
```

но он ставится через npm и я не нашел готовый, скачиваемый с cdn, файл

Comment: спасибо, но выдает ошибку все равно. код можете посмотреть в сообщение. теперь ругается "Unexpected token" --  
  class Timer extends React.Component{
>  getInitialState: function(){
                      ^
    return{
     seconds: 0
   };

Comment: Так работает или ошибку выдает? (в ответе написано "так работает")

Comment: "Unexpected token" - я не учел, что вы грузите реакт с cdn, webpack, babel у вас скорей всего не используется и возможно синтаксис es2016 не прокатывает в браузере

Answer (score 0):

Вот так работает все.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'


class Timer extends Component{
 constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = { seconds: 0 };
  }
  componentDidMount(){
   this.timer = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
  }

  tick(){
   this.setState(prevState => ({
        seconds: prevState.seconds + 1
    }));
}

  componentWillUnmount(){
   clearInterval(this.timer);
  }

  render(){
   return(
    <h5>Прошло: {this.state.seconds}</h5>
   )
  }
}

export default Timer
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```